# convert python dataframe to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I have a Python dataFrame with multiple columns.

```
  LogBlk    Page                                    BayFail       
  0          0                                 [0, 1, 8, 9]  
  1          16           [0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14]  
  2          32           [0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14]  
  3          48           [0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14]
```

I want to find BayFails that is associated with LogBlk=0, and Page=0.

```
df2 = df[ (df['Page'] == 16) & (df['LogBlk'] == 0) ]['BayFail']
```

This will return [0,1,8,9]

What I want to do is to convert this pandas.series into a list. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 37):

`pandas.Series`, has a [`tolist` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html#numpy-ndarray-tolist):

```
In [10]: import pandas as pd

In [11]: s = pd.Series([0,1,8,9], name = 'BayFail')

In [12]: s.tolist()
Out[12]: [0L, 1L, 8L, 9L]
```

---

Technical note: In my original answer I said that `Series` was a subclass of `numpy.ndarray` and inherited its `tolist` method. While that's true for Pandas version 0.12 or older, In the soon-to-be-released Pandas version 0.13, `Series` has been refactored to be a subclass of `NDFrame`. `Series` still has a `tolist` method, but it has no direct relationship to the `numpy.ndarray` method of the same name.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why tolist() breaks the naming convention for python methods? DataFrame's equivalent method is to_list(), I believe.

Comment: @HenryHenrinson: In the old days, Pandas Series were a subclass of NumPy ndarrays. `ndarrays` have a [`tolist` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html). The Series `tolist` method [*overrode* the ndarray method](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2447) to handle datetime64s differently. So the break in naming convention is a hang-over from NumPy's naming convention. You are right that nowadays it should be `to_list` to conform with all the other Series and DataFrame `to_*` methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can also convert them to `numpy arrays`

```
In [124]: s = pd.Series([0,1,8,9], name='BayFail')

In [125]: a = pd.np.array(s)
Out[125]: array([0, 1, 8, 9], dtype=int64)

In [126]: a[0]
Out[126]: 0
```